# Filter not triggered on second input update in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat list, where I can manually input value on every field or I can input in sum input, and in every input in ng-repeat change value by this sum.
Problem is, on `ng-repeat init`, I sum all number in the new input field, and when I change directly in `ng-repeat` value, filter successfully sums all `ng-repeat` value. 
If I in sum box input another value, I get in all `ng-repeat` new value depending on the sum number.

But, if I try, after this directly change the value in `ng-repeat` list, the sum filter not triggered.

**[Working plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZP46CNKXk9N7FAtl)**

Here is html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-init="storeValueOnScope($index, item)">
  <input type="number" ng-model="item.campaign_impressions" name="item"  ng-value="item" ng-blur="sendCustomSelectedImpressionsPerBench($index, item.campaign_impressions);">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="sumImpressions">Sum: </label>
        <input type="number" class="inputPolje" ng-model="campaignViewsTotalGoal" ng-change="getUserSelectedImpresion(campaignViewsTotalGoal)"
          ng-name="sumImpressions" 
          ng-value="items | sumOfValue:'campaign_impressions'">
</div>
```

Here is filter

```
 myApp.filter('sumOfValue', function() {
 return function(data, key) {
if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
  return 0;
var sum = 0;

angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
  sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
});
return sum;
}
});
```

Comment: [You should avoid using `ngModel` with `ngValue` on an `input[type="text"]`.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

Comment: @tsh i don't know how tu use this filter on ng-model

Comment: ng-model need left value, so no filters. You need implement this in your controller.

Comment: i try this http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZP46CNKXk9N7FAtl